# Get Last Visited URL in Chrome and other browser's

Tags: android, android-browser, android-cursor

I want to get last visited URL in chrome and other browser's. I am able to get Last URL in android Native browser. I use following code for this -

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
            new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL }, null, null,
            BookmarkColumns.DATE + " DESC");
    if (cur != null && cur.getCount() > 0) {
        cur.moveToFirst();
        String url = cur.getString(cur
                .getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL));
        cur.close();
        return url;
    } else {
        if (cur != null) {
            cur.close();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But this code does not work on other browser's like chrome. How can I get Last visited url in chrome and other browsers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

For chrome, you can use this uri:

```
Uri chromeUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks");
```

Column names for URL and date are the same: "url" and "date".

For other browsers, as it is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393318/how-to-get-browser-history-in-android), there is no common solution and, probably, BOOKMARKS_URI won't work.

Comment: can you share complete code to get the last visited url in chrome?