# Java/Android. How to get a list URLs of open tabs in Google Chrome?

Tags: java, android, google-chrome, android-studio

Just started to learn Android. I want to get the number and a list of open tabs (and ***URLs from this tabs***) in **Google Chrome**  using *Java+Android*. But I'm not sure whether to implement this? Can you help me with this question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I realize it's not possible. You can get the browser history though. The history can be a little outdated and doesn't reflect the current open tabs.

For specifics you may check the answer to the following question:

[Get Last Visited URL in Chrome and other browser's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465266/get-last-visited-url-in-chrome-and-other-browsers)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979583/how-can-i-get-the-url-for-a-google-chrome-tab?rq=1 but in this question use extension, I think that, maybe, there is a way for Java/Android.

Comment: chrome extension is not available in android