# copy link from Browser automatically

Tags: java, android

how do i copy **link** aotumatically from browser on android ***Without*** going through the copy button ?

i want to copy the url after checking  the bar link if is it filled

Comment: What should the "Blockquote" mean? Isn't it mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Thats **not** possible unless you program your own browser app.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the current tab's URL. However, this might be useful: [Get Last Visited URL in Chrome and other browser's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20465266/get-last-visited-url-in-chrome-and-other-browsers)

Comment: i dont mean the bookmark but the current url  before browsing
i want to check the url by my app before browsing

Comment: Is it your browsing app?